# What is the best way to reuse form components in React?

Tags: reactjs, forms, reusability, code-duplication

I have around 20 forms in my app where most of them includes similar input fields. A single form would look like this.

```
<form>
  <div>
    <input name="first_name" />
    <error />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="last_name" />
    <error />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="phone" />
    <error />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="address" />
    <error />
  </div>
</form>
```

**first_name, last_name** fields can be categorized as a common input group that will on most forms. **phone and address** group also can be found in many forms. Like-wise there are input groups that are common.

I'm trying to re-use the common ones. And found two ways.

1. Wrap common fields into components

This will be something like this

```
<form>
  <SectionOne />
  ...
</form>

const SectionOne = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <input name="first_name" />
        <error />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input name="last_name" />
        <error />
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

2. Wrap input and error

This will be something like this

```
<form>
  <Input 
    ....
  />
  <Input 
    ....
  />
  ...
</form>

const Input = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input name="first_name" />
      <error />
    </div>
  )
}
```

I would like to know which will be the best practice when building reusable app in the long run without duplication.

If I'm missing any other best practice I would like to know.

input means text boxes, selects, radio buttons etc.

Answer (score -1):

***Create pure component***

```
const Input = inputs => inputs.map(input => ( <><input name={input} /> <error/></>))
```

***Reuse it somewhere***

```
<Input inputs={['first_name', 'last_name']} />
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good practice. not scalable for selects, radio buttons etc.